# Access Module functions everywhere in phtml

Tags: magento, magento2

How can I create a Magento 2 module which extends a given class and be able to call my newly defined functions everywhere in every .phtml in Magento?

I've tried creating my module this is the Block:

etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Chapagain_HelloWorld" setup_version="1.0.0" schema_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Footer"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Block/HelloWorld.php

```
<?php
namespace Chapagain\HelloWorld\Block;
class HelloWorld extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_storeManager;    

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,        
        array $data = []
    )
    {        
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;        
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Get store identifier
     *
     * @return  int
     */
    public function getStoreId()
    {
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();
    }

    /**
     * Get website identifier
     *
     * @return string|int|null
     */
    public function getWebsiteId()
    {
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
    }

    /**
     * Get Store code
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getStoreCode()
    {
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getCode();
    }

    /**
     * Get Store name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getStoreName()
    {
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getName();
    }

    /**
     * Get current url for store
     *
     * @param bool|string $fromStore Include/Exclude from_store parameter from URL
     * @return string     
     */
    public function getStoreUrl($fromStore = true)
    {
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getCurrentUrl($fromStore);
    }

    /**
     * Check if store is active
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function isStoreActive()
    {
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->isActive();
    }
}
?>
```

later I try to call the functions in both footer.phtml & header.phtml (where I need them)

```
<?php 
echo $block->getStoreId() . '<br />';
echo $block->getStoreCode() . '<br />';
echo $block->getWebsiteId() . '<br />';
echo $block->getStoreName() . '<br />';
echo $block->getStoreUrl() . '<br />';
echo $block->isStoreActive() . '<br />';
?>
```

<del>but Magento doesn't allows me to do it.</del>

functions above doesn't echo nothing, functions are NULL.

Comment: What do you mean by "Magento doesn't allow me to do it"? Be specific about the problem you are facing.

Comment: @tvo functions return NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are extending the right block. If you want to extend header, or footer, find the original locations, than step out few folders back, until you find layouts folder, that browse through files inside, until you find where this template is called. You will see it is attached to some kind of block. Copy/paste it's name, and put it in your 'Class *** extends [paste here]'. Now feel free to code your code. Now, create a file with the same name as the original layout file in your module, having the same path to it (I mean, path after layout/ folder). Use XML setTemplate action to replace block's template to yours (can be done by adding 'Your_Module::[path to your template after /templates folder]'). You are almost ready. Now open your template overrides and add some calls to your custom methods. If all done correctly you should see an correct output.

Some tips, also:

- Don't use '_' for protected variables. Use simply 'storeManager' instead of 'storeManager'.
- Better type use [class you are making dependency to]. It helps your coded cleaner. So instead of this: **Class HelloWorld extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template** , use this: **use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template; Class HelloWorld extends Template**